# Reading continuously incoming data (usb4java)

Tags: java, usb, libusb-1.0, libusb-win32, usb4java

I have spent a considerable amount of time trying to figure out the best way of reading continuously a large amount of data using the Low-level functions of usb4java (Libusb).

The amount of data I need to read is 640kbyte/s in a Full Speed device, theoretically is possible, and I should be using less than half of the bandwidth available. The problem I am having is that the data I am reading has glitches that could be coming from either missing or corrupt data.

I have tried both Sync and Async with similar results. Here I post the code I am using to do this in Async mode, any help is appreciated.

```
public Void doInBackground() {

    loop = true;
    handle = comm_device_async.gethandle();

    buffer = BufferUtils.allocateByteBuffer(PacketSize).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    Transfer transfer = LibUsb.allocTransfer();

    LibUsb.fillBulkTransfer(transfer, handle, IN_ENDPOINT, buffer, read_callback, null, TIMEOUT);
    int result = LibUsb.submitTransfer(transfer);
    if (result != LibUsb.SUCCESS) {
        throw new LibUsbException("Unable to submit transfer", result);
    }

    while (loop) {
        synchronized (synchObj) {
            while (!transfercompleted) {
                try {
                    synchObj.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(GraphPanel_JChart2D.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
        transfercompleted = false;

        multipledatashort[readcyclecount] = read_callback_data;
        readcyclecount++;
        if (readcyclecount == readcycles) {
            synchronized (dataListShort) {
                dataListShort.add(multipledatashort);
                dataListShort.notify();
            }
            readcyclecount = 0;
        }

    }
    return null;
}

TransferCallback read_callback = new TransferCallback() {

    ByteBuffer buffer;
    long startTime = 0;

    @Override
    public void processTransfer(Transfer transfer) {
        System.out.println("ReadCallback loop time " + (System.nanoTime() / 1000 - startTime));
        startTime = System.nanoTime() / 1000;
        read_callback_data = new short[transfer.buffer().capacity() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < read_callback_data.length; i++)
            read_callback_data[i] = transfer.buffer().getShort();


        synchronized (synchObj) {
            transfercompleted = true;
            synchObj.notify();
        }

        buffer = BufferUtils.allocateByteBuffer(PacketSize).order(
                ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        LibUsb.fillBulkTransfer(transfer, collectWorker_usb4java_async_fast.handle, IN_ENDPOINT, buffer,
                read_callback, null, TIMEOUT);
        int result = LibUsb.submitTransfer(transfer);
        if (result != LibUsb.SUCCESS) {
            throw new LibUsbException("Unable to submit transfer", result);
        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a thread that describes pretty a similar issue

http://libusb.6.n5.nabble.com/Fwd-FT2232H-asynchronous-maximum-data-rates-td4519549.html

There are two main points

1. > He is saying submitting a single request asynchronously (and
   >   resubmitting it) turns out to work worse than submitting synchronous
   >   requests. This is expected, doing more busywork takes more time.
2. > the goal is to keep the list of URB's at the kernel constantly filled.
   >   Anytime that list empties, there's a chance it won't be refilled in
   >   time to request data and the FT2232H buffer will fill up. So the
   >   *right* way to do the asynchronous mode is to make a list of transfers. Each time one of them returns, another is requested.
   >   There's overhead involved in converting this request into the
   >   corresponding list of URBs, but as long as the list starts out big
   >   enough, we can amortize this overhead over the time the other
   >   transfers take to complete

So basically for large amount of data we need to have a buffer of transactions to be submitted, so there is always one pending when the last one ends.

I am going to be working on that, but I haven't found any good examples of how this should be done using usb4java. Again, any help is appreciated